# Eigenfrequencies of Hamiltonian dynamical systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, nonlinear-dynamics

Consider the Hamiltonian 
$$
   H=H(x,y,p_x,p_y)
$$
which generates the dynamical system
$$ 
  \dot{x}=+\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_x}
$$
$$ 
  \dot{y}=+\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_y}
$$
$$ 
  \dot{p_x}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}
$$
$$ 
  \dot{p_y}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial y}
$$
I then discover that this system admits a certain fixed point
$$
    \vec{z}_0:=(x_0,\,y_0,\,p_{x,0},\,p_{y,0})
$$
To determine the stability properties of $\vec{z}_0$, I compute the Jacobian matrix $J$ associated to the dynamical system, I evaluate it at fixed point $\vec{z}_0$, and I compute the eigenvalues, which are of the type:
$$
    \lambda_1=+i\omega_a
$$
$$
    \lambda_2=-i\omega_a
$$
$$
    \lambda_3=+i\omega_b
$$
$$
    \lambda_4=-i\omega_b
$$
Therefore, I can recognize the presence of two characteristic frequencies, namely $\omega_a$ and $\omega_b$.

So far, so good.

At this point, I try to do the same computation with a different set of dynamical variables, for example making use of polar coordinates instead of cartesian coordinates. So, I start from Hamiltonian 
$$
   H^\prime=H^\prime(r,\theta,p_r,p_\theta),
$$
I find the same fixed point found before, but now written in polar coordinates, i.e. $\vec{z}_0^\prime=(r_0,\theta_0,p_{r,0},p_{\theta,0})$. I then compute the Jacobian matrix $J^\prime$ associated to $H^\prime$, evaluate it at fixed point $\vec{z}_0^\prime$ and compute its eigenvalues. The latter have the following structure: 
$$
    \lambda_1^\prime=+i\omega_a^\prime
$$
$$
    \lambda_2^\prime=-i\omega_a^\prime
$$
$$
    \lambda_3^\prime=+i\omega_b^\prime
$$
$$
    \lambda_4^\prime=-i\omega_b^\prime
$$
So, i can recognize two characteristic frequencies: $\omega_a^\prime$ and $\omega_b^\prime$.

What I find really counterintuitive is that
$$
    \omega_a\neq\omega_a^\prime
$$
$$
    \omega_b\neq\omega_b^\prime
$$
that means that, the two eigenfrequencies are different in the two schemes (the cartesian one and the polar one) that I developed. I would have expected them to be the same, i.e. that $\omega_a=\omega_a^\prime$ and $\omega_b=\omega_b^\prime$.

So, here my question comes: is it possible that different set of dynamical variables lead to different characteristic frequencies for a certain fixed point?

To be noted: actually the two sets of eigenfrequencies, i.e. $\{\omega_a, \omega_b\}$ and $\{\omega_a^\prime, \omega_b^\prime\}$ include similar terms and one can obtain the frequencies in the first set by properly combining the ones in the second set, and viceversa. But, as I said, I expected the two sets to be really identical.

Comment: Just an idea: as far as I understand going to regular polar coordinates is not a [canonical transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation). You can make a change of variables in equations of motion and get system $S^\prime$. You can plug the same change of variable into Hamiltonian $H$ and get new Hamiltonian $H^\prime$. But the system $S^{''}$, derived from $H^\prime$, is not necessarily the same as $S^\prime$: that happens only when change of coordinates is a canonical transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So, according to your explanation, it is not a surprise that I find $\omega_a\neq\omega_a^\prime$ and $\omega_b\neq\omega_b^\prime$ ?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this is the most plausible explanation. Note that if you explicitly write system $S'$ then an equilibrium must have the same eigenvalues as in a system $S$.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your last comment. I started from a certain Hamiltonian $H$, wrote the ensuing dynamical system $S$, found an equilibrium $\vec{z}_0$ and computed  the eigenvalues $\lambda_j$s of the associated Jacobian matrix. Then, I move from cartesian to polar coordinates (which is not a canonical transf). As a consequence, $H$ turns into $H^\prime$. This Hamiltonian generates dynamical system $S^\prime$. I determine the point of equilibrium $\vec{z}_0^\prime$ and the eigenvalues of its Jacobian, $\lambda_j^\prime$s. Is it ok that the two set of eigenvalues are different?

Comment: There are two ways to get new system using change of coordinates. The first one (which gets you $S'$ in my notation) is done with usual change of variables in a system of ODEs. The second one (which get you $S''$) is that you use transformation to change Hamiltonian from $H$ to $H'$ and after that write Hamiltonian equations for $H'$. If going to polar coordinates was a canonical transformation $S'$ and $S''$ would be the same systems.